# How to make sure data is ready before calling a hook in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

I have a hook that calls two React Query hooks for fetching data.
After those calls, I call another hook to grab other stuff.

So one single hook cals 3 hooks.

I want the third hook call to **wait** for the data from one of the previous queries but
I am having no success so far.

The code is something like this:  (generic)

```
export const useGetValues = () => {
  const [state1, setState1] = useState<string>('');
  const [state2, setState2] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const {
    data: data1,
    isLoading: isLoadingData1,
    isError: isError1,
  } = useQueryData1();

  const {
    data: data2,
    isLoading: isLoadingData2,
    isError: isError2,
  } = useQueryData2();

  const { stuff } = useGetSomeStuff(data2);

  ...
}
```

So, I need **data2** to be ready (available) **before** sending it to the other hook.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want the third query to wait for both previous queries or just either one?

Comment: Have you considered creating a separate async function that does all these steps? Doing this all with hooks is going to suck and make it a lot harder to read.

Comment: another option is to lump query2 and query3 together in the same useQuery fetch function

Comment: Actually, your demand implies to call a hook conditionally. You say that "hey, dear hook, do your job only if something else is already happened". This is technically possible via useEffect, short circuting in the hook call etc, but it's an antipattern. It's better for you to rewrite the whole code in a different fashion.

Answer (score 0):

React-query provides an [`enabled` property in the config](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/disabling-queries). Use it to only enable the third query when `data2` is ready:

```js
const useGetSomeStuff = (data) => {
  return useQuery(["someKey", data], async () => {...}, {
    enabled: !!data // enable if data is ok
  })
}


export const useGetValues = () => {
  const [state1, setState1] = useState<string>('');
  const [state2, setState2] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const {
    data: data1,
    isLoading: isLoadingData1,
    isError: isError1,
  } = useQueryData1();

  const {
    data: data2,
    isLoading: isLoadingData2,
    isError: isError2,
  } = useQueryData2();

  const { stuff } = useGetSomeStuff(data2);
}
```